# How to use a segue when prototype cells are not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an RSS reader that displays the feed and then when a custom cell is clicked should bring you to the article. It was all working correctly but then I changed it so that it would work with custom cells. In order to do this I had to delete all the prototype cells from the storyboard which subsequently deleted the segue between the cell and the detail view. When I add a prototype cell back in the app crashes without any errors. I am very confused. How can I bring this to a detail view without using prototype cells or a segue? I tried didSelectRowAtIndexPath but this is a UIViewController not a UITableViewController. My code for the tableview is below let me know if you have any ideas..

```
#import "APPMasterViewController.h"

    #import "APPDetailViewController.h"
    #import "IITableViewCell.h"

    @interface APPMasterViewController () {
        NSXMLParser *parser;
        NSMutableArray *feeds;
        NSMutableDictionary *item;
        NSMutableString *title;
        NSMutableString *link;
        NSString *element;
    }
    @end

    @implementation APPMasterViewController

    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {
        [super awakeFromNib];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

        feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/?feed=rss"];
        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [parser parse];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table View

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return feeds.count;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"IITableViewCell";

        IITableViewCell *cell = (IITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IITableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.mainTextLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

        element = elementName;

        if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

            item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        }

    }


    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

            [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
            [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

            [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

        }

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

        if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
            [title appendString:string];
        } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
            [link appendString:string];
        }

    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        return 78;
    }


    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
            [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

        }
    }

    @end
```

Comment: There will be a crash message - try setting an exception breakpoint

Comment: Have you remade the segues from your custom cell prototypes? There's no difference in the way a segue works with a custom cell vs. a standard UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you are using an UIViewController, you just need to implement the UITableViewDelegate protocol to enable:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You can set the delegate in your UIViewController's viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  self.tableView.delegate = self;
  // UITableViewDataSource is another protocol you should implement
  self.tableView.dataSource = self;

}
```

You can set up the segue by CTRL dragging towards the next view controller. Make sure your set the identifier of the segue, in this case "MySegue"
[image: Setting up segue]

Next implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:cell];
}
```

In this method you call the segue, you can send any id as the sender, in this particular case we are sending the cell

Afterwards if you want to prepare for the segue implement the following method available on any UIViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        // prepare for segue here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is your issue, but as a general rule, you add a custom cell by specifying the name of the cell in the identifier input, so that you can refer to it in the code.

Then, you can ctrl+click to your cell, then drag to the detail view controller of your choice in your storyboard, you select the kind of segue you want, then you click on segue and you set an identifier in the attributes panel. And you refer to this segue in the code, in the method `prepareForSegue` or `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Does that answer your question?